# tkinter close both pop ups

Tags: python, tkinter

Beginner pythonner here.

I have a question, I am making a pop up window which displays the week number.

But I am getting a double tkinter window, and when I press `Okay` it only closes one window (the one displaying the week number) and leaves the other one open.

I tried commenting all the lines to see which one opens the 2nd tkinter but I can't find it. Can someone help me? Either close both windows when I press okay or not open the 2nd window at all?

Thanks in advance!

(also without you guys and this community i would have never learn to program so thank you all!)

Here is the code:

```
root = tk.Tk()

def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Toplevel(root)
    popup.wm_title("weeknummer")
    popup.tkraise(root) 
    tk.Label(popup, text=msg).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy).pack()

popupmsg('het is weeknummer {}'.format(weeknummer))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `root` is your root window. `popup` is your `Toplevel` window. In order to close both, you can simply use `command=root.destroy`. when a parent gets destroyed, the child widgets will also be destroyed.

Comment: `popup = tk.Toplevel(root)` is opening the second window. If you do not want two windows then do not ask for two windows.

Comment: Thank you all, it work changed command = popup.destroy for command=root.destroy. Also thank you all for the explanetion! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'other' window is the root window.

```
import tkinter as tk


def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Toplevel(root)
    popup.wm_title("weeknummer")
    tk.Label(popup, text=msg).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy).pack()


root = tk.Tk()

weeknummer = 2
message = f'het is weeknummer {weeknummer}'

tk.Label(root, text='This is the root').pack()
tk.Button(root, text='spawn popup', command=lambda msg=message: popupmsg(msg)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively, in lieu of creating your own `Toplevel` window, you could use a `tkinter` [standard dialog widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm).